# 3D flip with scg path and raphaeljs

Tags: html, css, svg, raphael, transformation

I am using [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw some hexagon shapes using rapheal's .path() method. That works pretty well. Now I want to rotate the shape around the y-axis to crate a 3d flip effect and to show the "back" of the shape when the user hovers over the shape. As far as I found out, something like rotateY is not yet possible with svg, is that correct?

My question is: Is there another way to make this effect? Maybe using CSS Transitions? (this would probably not work in IE < 9) or to fake the effect using some sort of the 3x3 transformation matrix?

Also I have found [this](http://code.google.com/p/svg3d/), but I am not sure if it would help me and how to use it together with raphaeljs :(

Thanks for any help!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip an object in the y axis by applying a scale(1, -1) transform to it. If you want to animate the flip you need to animate the transform gradually from scale(1, 1) to scale(1, -1)

Here's a simple example of the basic concept in raw SVG.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(0, 100)">
    <path transform="translate(0, -50)" fill="red"  d="M 75,10 L 25,90 L 125,90 z">
      <set attributeName="fill" to="lime" begin="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML" type="scale" from="1, 1" to="1, -1" dur="1s" additive="sum" fill="freeze" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

You could use raphael to manipulate the shape at the halfway point instead of the simple SMIL fill change I've used so that it looks like you're seeing the back of the shape. And you could also use raphael to do the animation although raphael won't do SMIL so you'd have to use raphael and javascript together to manipulate the transform attribute so that it gradually changes from scale(1, 1) to scale(1, -1).